# Connecting to localhost on mac with an ipad

Tags: macos, localhost, remote-access

I would like to connect an ipad to localhost:5000 on my macbook. The purpose is that I would like to test how my website looks on the ipad. I followed the steps I found on numerous websites, meaning

1. I got the name (or ip address) of the macbook with

   ipconfig getifaddr $(route -n get default|awk '/interface/ { print $2 }')

which gave 192.268.42.20. So this is the internal ip address within the network created by my rooter. My ipad is also within that network.

2. I turned off the firewall on the mac. I did not think that is necessary, but I did it anyway.
3. I went to System Preferences -> Sharing -> enabled Remote Management (here one can find the computer name, but it doesn't make a difference whether I use the ip address or the computer name)
4. Now I should be able to connect to the localhost on the mac with

   http://192.168.42.20:5000

but this does not work. I get the message

```
This web page is not available
```

I use a Mac book running High Sierra, 10.13.6. Any idea what I might do wrong?

EDIT: Still no luck with this, but I got something working with

```
ngrok http 5000
```

see https://ngrok.com/docs. This works for what I need...

Comment: Are you serving your website using an HTTP or an HTTPS server? Also, did you verify it is accessible from your MacBook? http://192.168.42.20:5000 should load on your machine the same way it would on your iPad.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the devices are on the same network, that should work. If they are not, you would have to enable [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).
Try restarting both devices, then rechecking the IP address.
Make sure the server is running with no errors.
Also verify that you can access the page from the MacBook itself.
Aside from that, I don't know why it would not be working.